# how can i upload documents in salesliterature entity in MSCRM 4.0 by custom code?

Tags: asp.net-ajax, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

how can i upload documents in salesliterature entity in MSCRM 4.0 by custom code?

Can anyone help me with code snippets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey...I found the answer...its quite simple..

```
        salesliteratureitem slsLtrItm = new salesliteratureitem();

        Lookup lookUpSalesLiteratureId = new Lookup();
        lookUpSalesLiteratureId.Value = new Guid(salesLiteratuteItem.salesliteratureid.Value.ToString());

        slsLtrItm.salesliteratureid = lookUpSalesLiteratureId;
        slsLtrItm.title = salesLiteratuteItem.title;

        //Read when the file is attached
        FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(salesLiteratuteItem.attacheddocumenturl);
        byte[] byteData = new byte[stream.Length];
        stream.Read(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
        stream.Close();

        // Encode the data using base64.
        string encodedData = System.Convert.ToBase64String(byteData);

        //provide all required details
        slsLtrItm.documentbody = encodedData;
        slsLtrItm.filename = salesLiteratuteItem.filename;
        slsLtrItm.@abstract = salesLiteratuteItem.@abstract;
        slsLtrItm.authorname = salesLiteratuteItem.authorname;
        slsLtrItm.documentbody = salesLiteratuteItem.documentbody;
        slsLtrItm.iscustomerviewable = new CrmBoolean();
        slsLtrItm.iscustomerviewable.Value = true;
        slsLtrItm.keywords = salesLiteratuteItem.keywords;
        slsLtrItm.mimetype = salesLiteratuteItem.mimetype;

        //create salesLiteratureItem
        Guid salesLiteratureItemid = crmService.Create(slsLtrItm);
```